# Unable to pull directory from remote host to local using rsync

Tags: linux, rsync, directory, solaris

My issue is a a small part of a bigger problem i m trying to resolve.

The issue started with `rsync` command that was very complex and constructed by ansible and does not work ... reported here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859216/ansible-synchronize-module-fails-to-get-directory-from-remote-to-local-failed

I wish to start off with a simple rsync command to copy a folder from remote host to local.

It copies is the remote is a file but fails if the remote is a directory.

```
$ /bin/rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
[mylocaluser@mylocalhost myremotehost]$ uname -a
Linux mylocalhost 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 26 14:15:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Rsync working for a file:

```
$ /bin/rsync -v myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments/pay.war /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/

This system is for the use by authorized users only. All data contained
on all systems is owned by the company and may be monitored, intercepted,
recorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any
manner, by authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)
have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Unauthorized or improper
use of this system may result in administrative, disciplinary action, civil
and criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or
unauthorized, constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,
recording, reading, copying, or capturing and disclosure.

IF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.

##################################################################
# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
# ***    password when logging in                            *** #
##################################################################

pay.war

sent 43 bytes  received 83 bytes  252.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

However, when i give the directory instead of a file it does not work.

```
$ /bin/rsync -v myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments/ /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/

This system is for the use by authorized users only. All data contained
on all systems is owned by the company and may be monitored, intercepted,
recorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any
manner, by authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)
have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Unauthorized or improper
use of this system may result in administrative, disciplinary action, civil
and criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or
unauthorized, constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,
recording, reading, copying, or capturing and disclosure.

IF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.

##################################################################
# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
# ***    password when logging in                            *** #
##################################################################

skipping directory .

sent 8 bytes  received 30 bytes  25.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `rsync --help`:

> --recursive, -r          recurse into directories

So when you want to copy a directory, you have to add `-r` or `--recursive` option to `rysnc:`

```bash
/bin/rsync -rv myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments/ /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/
```

Comment: The `-a` flag is usually better than a bare `-r`, since it includes options to make rsync handle symlinks and device files in ways that are usually the right ones.

Comment: @SottoVoce thanks! I did not remember that option.  It's also useful for preserving the owner and group of the files.

Comment: For rsync efficiency you should include `-t` so that file times are also copied. (This is implied with `-a`.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync -a` instead of plain `rsync`.

Without the `-a` (`--archive`) flag you will neither copy recursively nor will you get file metadata. At a minimum, the file modification time (`mtime`) that's copied with `-t` (`--times`) is required for `rsync` to be able to selectively skip files that it considers to be already copied. If `rsync` determines that a file's size and last modified time are the same on source and destination it prefers to avoid performing a checksum, but obviously without the file modification time being copied to the destination these will not match and `rsync` cannot optimise its transfer algorithm.